# Dynamically set the height of uitextview like message app

Tags: ios, height, uitextview

i am having a problem of setting the height of `UITextView` like message app. it's achieved by increasing the height of it when ever a newline occurs.

my problem is that when the user edits the text content then it's not decreasing the height of the Container, in which `textview` is a child.

I am using Auto Layout and this code

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    UITextPosition* pos = self.posttextView.endOfDocument;//explore others like beginningOfDocument if you want to customize the behaviour
    CGRect currentRect = [self.posttextView caretRectForPosition:pos];

    if (currentRect.origin.y > previousRect.origin.y){    
        if (self.containerHeightt.constant == 99) {        
            return;
        }

        self.containerHeightt.constant += 10;

        NSLog(@"the container height is %f",self.containerHeightt.constant);   
    }

    previousRect = currentRect;
}
```

Please tell me how to detect when a line gets deleted from the `textview`, thereafter reducing the height of the container.

Comment: Have you tried just using the `contentSize` of the text view ?

Comment: no i didnt try in that way.

Comment: i can increase the size of the container when a new line appear but how to decrease its height when a line removed from the UITextView.As i said i am using AutoLayout

Comment: I mean use the `contentSize` to find out the desired height and use that as the constraint constant

Answer (score 1):

Please below way -

Make sure your UITextView Scrolling is disable.

Add a dummy UITextView height constraint with default height, connect it with

```
IBOutlet (NSLayoutConstraint - textViewHeightConstraint). 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *textViewHeightConstraint;


- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    return YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    CGFloat myMaxSize = 480.0f; 

    CGRect frameRect = textView.frame;
    CGRect rect = [textView.text 
boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(frameRect.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin 
          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: textView.font} 
             context:nil];

    CGSize size = rect.size;
    if (size.height > myMaxSize) {
        size.height = myMaxSize;
        [textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    }

    frameRect.size = size;

    self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = size.height;  

}
```

Comment: i tried this code but i didnt get any change i supposed to get.my textview is in a uiview,i want to chane the uiview height when there is change in the uitextview content.I am using Auto Layout.

Comment: Ok then try to change UIview also and called [view layoutIfNeeded]

Comment: instead of setting the frame use the frame to set the constraint constant

Comment: @user3563618 I have update code above and tested with same with my system . Please change the height of super View in same way.